# How to implement bottom navigation using activities in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an error when trying to use startActivity(intent) when an item is clicked on the navigation bar. Where am I going with my code?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        binding.logout.setOnClickListener {
            firebaseAuth.signOut()
                val intent = Intent(this, Login::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
        }
       //here is the buttom Nav bar, the setOnNavItemListener is also striken through
        binding.bottomNavView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when(it.itemId){
```

error is here when I try to start another activity after click

```
                R.id.drinks -> startActivity(this, drinks::class.java)
                R.id.profileScreen ->
                R.id.others ->
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a best practice model to implement Bottom Nav using Kotlin:

**Now bottom nav is integrated with nav controller**

[image: bottom nav]

Bottom Navigation works with the concept of fragments.

Each of the pages which appear on clicking the bottom nav item is called a fragment.

**Bottom Nav item = Fragment**

**Creating Menu Items**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="@string/home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:title="@string/messages"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_message_24"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:title="@string/profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_profile_24"/>
</menu>
```

**Adding Bottom Nav in Activity main.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

**Add Navigation Resource file**

[image: navigation resource]

In bottom_nav.xml, add the 3 fragments - Home, Messages and Profile

All these 3 are top level fragments and not linked to each other

**Important:** Make Sure that the id of fragments in navigation resource file is same as the id of menu items

**Add Nav Host Fragment to Activity Main.xml**

Drag and Drop - nav host fragment to activity main.xml and add bottom_nav.xml created in previous step to it

In bottom navigation component in activity main.xml, add `app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"` to link the menu

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

**MainActivity.kt**

We need to activate the respective menus in MainActivity file

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Setting bottom nav with nav controller
        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigationView)
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController
        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but what if I want to use bottom Navigation with activities instead.